# Android Studio Flamingo new UI doesn't have device selection option

Tags: android, android-studio

I've recently updated to Android studio flamingo and enabled the fresh new UI. Everything is fine here but in the previous android studio ui there was a device selection option on the topbar with the run icon. But with new UI I didn't find the device selection on the top bar. Is there any way to enable it on the topbar?

Android studio Run option icon on top bar:

[image]

Comment: That's Flamingo? It doesn't look anything like it does on my Mac. Are yoou running some kind of custom theme? maybe that's hiding away what you're looking for?

Comment: No it's Android Studio Flamingo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that we can add it manually:

- Right click on toolbar and select `Customize Toolbar`
  [image]
- Select `Run with Options` then tap the plus icon, select `Add Action...`
  [image]
- Now you can find the `Select Device` action, add it
  [image]